# iOS - How to create a striped image?

Tags: ios, swift, image

I want to set a striped background to my UIView.
How do I create a simple striped image in Swift?

Example:
[image: stripped image]

Thank you!

Update:

Thanks to Simon Gladman, I created a function to make a striped image, but I did not manage to do the rotation, maybe because of the `fromRect` attributes.

```
// create a striped color
func strippedColor(color1: UIColor, _ color2: UIColor, width: CGFloat = 1) -> UIColor {
    let context = CIContext()
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIStripesGenerator")!
    blurFilter.setValue(CIColor(color: color1), forKey: "inputColor0")
    blurFilter.setValue(CIColor(color: color2), forKey: "inputColor1")
    blurFilter.setValue(width, forKey: "inputWidth")
    let ref = context.createCGImage(blurFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2*width, height: 1))
    let ref2 = ref
    
    
    //let rotateFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIStraightenFilter")!
    //rotateFilter.setValue(CIImage(CGImage: ref), forKey: "inputImage")
    //rotateFilter.setValue(NSNumber(double: 2), forKey: "inputAngle")
    //let ref2 = context.createCGImage(rotateFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: rotateFilter.outputImage!.extent)
    
    let uiimage = UIImage(CGImage: ref2)
    let uicolor = UIColor(patternImage: uiimage)
    return uicolor
}
```

Comment: There are probably a gazillion ways to do this. What have you tried? Please share your code and tell us what issues you're having with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotation does not work in the (updated) original post because of the use of CIStraightenFilter. This filter is probably not meant to be used as a general rotation filter as it probably will just straighten the image :)

CIAffineTransform is better suited for that, I think.

The following example generates a stripe and rotates it 45 degrees and works well for me.

**Swift 3:**

```
fileprivate func generateImage(_ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let context = CIContext()
    let stripes = CIFilter(name: "CIStripesGenerator", withInputParameters: [
        "inputColor0" : CIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000),
        "inputColor1" : CIColor(red: 0.259, green: 0.259, blue: 0.259),
        "inputWidth" : NSNumber(value: 2.0),
        "inputSharpness" : NSNumber(value: 0.0)
    ])!.outputImage!

    let rotated = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform", withInputParameters: [
        "inputImage" : stripes,
        "inputTransform" : NSValue(cgAffineTransform: CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45.0))
    ])!.outputImage!
    return UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(rotated, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would use CoreImage's `CIStripesGenerator` filter to create the stripe pattern then chain it to a `CIStraightenFilter` to rotate it by 1/4 pi radians.

Creating the pattern with a filter gives you control at runtime over the stripe width and colours.

You can find out about Apple's CoreImage framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185).

Cheers!

Simon

Comment: Hi, 

`rotateFilter.setValue(blurFilter.outputImage!, forKey: "inputImage")`

Should work :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I will update my question to show what this gives me

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the CoreImage answer that Simon has given. It will give a lot of dynamic control.

If you are just creating the same pattern over and over then you can use this...

```
let stripedColor = UIColor(patternImage: stripedPatternImage)
```

The pattern image just contains a single "unit" of the stripe that repeats over and over creating the pattern you want.

Comment: thank you, but I need to create the pattern programmaticaly.